# Spring multiple Opened Connections

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I set up a new Spring Boot Application including only the `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` dependency and added basic mongodb configs (host, port, username, password, ..) in the application.properties.
When I execute the application the following appears in the console:

```
2020-12-27 23:30:21.306  INFO 25230 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:86}] to localhost:27017
2020-12-27 23:30:21.306  INFO 25230 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:87}] to localhost:27017
```

I am curios why the connection was opened twice by spring. Isn't one opened connection enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add the below line into your properties file.

```
spring.data.mongodb.min-connections-per-host=1
```

The default size is 2 for the MongoDB java driver.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thank you, yes it worked. But can yo explain me, why the default size is 2?  Why should there be 2 opened connections to the Database?

Comment: This is for connection pooling. It is always better to have a minimum connection greater than 1 (depends on your requirement). So most of the connection pooling provides an ideal/minimum pool size greater than 1.